# AngularJS page validation

Tags: angularjs

I am developing an AngularJS/Web Api application, is there any way that we can write any Page validations in C# code and can be called from AngularJS as a service call?
i.e. the C# code is converted to JSON object where the angularJS service read the JSON object to enable/disable other controls? With this approach i can keep all my validation logic in one centralised place.

I don't want to write the same validation logic in the Angular script.

Please suggest.
Thanks

Comment: This is very basic example which show how you can do "validation": http://plnkr.co/edit/jzSUDo But in my opinion if you want to get better answer you need to explain your ideas more detailed

Comment: I would like to enable disable controls based on selection of values in dropdown. I can handle this case writing a javascript. I want to achieve the same scenario where i can write C# code and renders this as JSON object and my angular can react based on the json object.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have only server-side validation. And at the same time you want your validation to happen asynchronously at server. And for end-user it would seem like a client-side validation.

Whether you are using Web API or Spring java, it is possible. There is a framework that can greatly simplify it. Just download example and see how it works:
[https://upida4net.codeplex.com](https://upida4net.codeplex.com/)

By the way, you can take a look at working example here: http://upida.cloudapp.net:8080/org.upida.example.angular/

I promise, you will be surprised with amount of code there.

Comment: thanks for the response and really good suggestions. Can you please share the links of sample code projects using upida and angular JS??

Regards

Comment: Examples are actually part of the upida.codeplex.com download. Just download the package and see examples inside. There are Angular, Knockout examples inside.